# JavaScript: Trace Running Code (Not a Stack Trace)

Tags: javascript, trace

In the Prehistoric Age, you could get a trace of running Basic which would dump line numbers onto the screen (or printer).

Using various debugging tools, such as those built in to Firefox, I can single step through JavaScript code.

Is there a tool which will *trace* running code to output? This could be in the form of source code line numbers or the text of a the currently executing line. The tool could be in an IDE, or a browser addon, or whatever is required.

Comment: You can use the profiling tools in Google Chrome to see which functions get executed and how much CPU/etc is spent on them. You can set breakpoints and inspect code in specific places. It makes less sense to talk about line numbers because you could put a whole program on one line in JS and you can do some very obscure things with closures..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
console.trace();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace

Comment: To trace from a specific point, I believe you can set a breakpoint then evaluate in console (at least in Chrome)

Comment: From the linked site: “Outputs a stack trace to the Web Console”. I wasn’t after a stack trace.